# How to show a "share" popover in a spotify app?

Tags: spotify

When developing a spotify app, how do I show a standard spotify "share" popover that will do the right thing for a song of choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, there's no public API for this. We'll be releasing an updated build soon that includes it.

Until then, you can use the following private API. Please note that you must move over the the public API once released if you want your application to be published in the App Finder:

```
sp.social.showSharePopup(x, y, uri);
```

... where x and y are the coordinates inside your app where the popup is to be shown.

Comment: Great! Now the problem is that playlists (always?) seem to have an empty uri property. We're creating our own, and everything else seems to be filled in, but the uri stays empty. Ideas?

Comment: Just to follow up on this, we just released a developer preview build that contains a public API for this. See the "Application" class in the reference (http://developer.spotify.com/download/spotify-apps-api/preview/reference/) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you want to use a jQuery selector on `anchorElement` I did like this:

```
$(target).on('click', function() {
    models.application.showSharePopup($(this).get(0), spotify:track:6JEK0CvvjDjjMUBFoXShNZ);
});
```